# POST http://exaple.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: opencart, http-status-code-500

I am new to opencart. Some how I managed to create a website after reading online tutorial.

The website was worked well, but since two day the add to cart button is not working. Its showing some error on console. I tried different browser but same result.

Here I attached the screenshot.[image: error 500]

The website is posakaworld.com

Any tips or hint is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I also having the similar issue, please check your

```
system/log/error.txt
```

For my case, I installed a new extension, and it shows and error

```
2017-06-25 9:49:03 - PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: checkCart in /Users/Shiro/Sites/opencart/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_checkout_cart.php on line 724
```

When I check ajax response, it does not show the error, it is due to production display error off, so finally, I manage to find out it is just a PHP Notice can break the system.

Once I fix the undefined variable notice, my ajax no more error. Everything back to normal. I hope this solution is helped.